# COM application comunication performance

Tags: performance, com

In my company we are evaluating if to switch from one application to another and I have some performance questions (which might be nonsense...) I have read some COM articles and the clearest thing I have is that it is language independent, but what about the performance?

We use a 3rd party electric grid solver trough a c# API, and we are not entirely happy with it. (Is using the API the same thing as COM?)

Competitors all use COM communication.

As the use we will give to the program will be in a stochastic simulation framework, is it worth to use COM communication? will it be very slow?

I have no experience with this at all, and I would like some light.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Overall COM performance is awesome. It does not mean though that performance is sufficient to hide/fix bad design elements, such as excessive calls, interprocess communication roundtrips etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Component vendors in general will favor a COM interface since that makes their product usable in a lot more runtime environments.  Including from languages like C++, Delphi or any scripting language.  And C#, the .NET framework has very good support for COM interop and it will *look* like a native C# interface.  Make sure that you are not already using COM and just don't know it.  You can get a hint from the deployment instructions, a COM component in general either requires a manifest or an installer.

A secondary consideration is that COM is often the advertized interface on products that have been around a long time, 10 or more years.  Which is likely for a generic "grid solver" type of product.  With the product stable with no new bells and whistles added for a decade.  This is something you want to watch out for, you typically will have trouble getting support for such products since the vendor doesn't have programmers working on the product anymore.  Having access to good support is always important when you replace a core library that your product depends on.

And support is especially important when you have perf problems.  There just isn't much you can do yourself to solve them, you really want to be able to work with the vendor to get them resolved.

COM is certainly no magic solution to a perf problem, if the source is api layer overhead. Which *might* be the case if the solver is a separate process, such interop is expensive.  Something you can easily see in Taskmgr.exe, Processes tab, you'll see another EXE pop up when you run your app.  Regardless, COM inevitably includes a thunk to go from managed to unmanaged code.  It is in general quite fast but if the api calls are very fine-grained then it can add up.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, now I get to know a little bit more, perhaps we are already using COM... We use a dll to call the program functionality, I don't know if that is COM or not.

Comment: Also thank you for the advice about the program being outdated, we'll be carefull

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two possibiities when doing COM communication: 1) in-process, 2) out-of-process.

If you want maximum performance, you really want to use in-process COM (your code will run in the same process as your client code, so there is no serialization or "marshaling" involved). In this case, there is not really any "communication" layer. COM is a very simple binary contract. It's described here: [The layout of a COM object](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/05/68017.aspx)

More info about v-table performance can be found here: [Virtual method table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)

Note there are some subtleties about in-process COM, especially [the threading model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809971.aspx). Even in-process you want to make sure you choose a threading model that will fit with your client/calling code. So in the "Mixed Model Development" chapter of the article, you want "direct access", not "marshaling" (in the table).